# Why fadeOut() wait delay() and hide() not?

Tags: jquery

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/RsVF2/) you will find an example :

```
<div id="first_div">First Div<div>
<div id="second_div">Second Div<div>

$('#first_div').show().delay(2000).fadeOut(300);
$('#second_div').show().delay(2000).hide();
```

as you can see, `fadeOut()` is called after 2 seconds; `hide()` is called immediatly. Why? `hide()` doesnt wait `delay()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Jquery Delay](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)

> Added to jQuery in version 1.4, the .delay() method allows us to delay
>   the execution of functions that follow it in the queue. It can be used
>   with the standard effects queue or with a custom queue. Only
>   subsequent events in a queue are delayed; for example this will not
>   delay the no-arguments forms of .show() or .hide() which do not use
>   the effects queue.

Basically, fadeOut uses effects queue and hence is delayed. But show(), hide() don't follow any queue

Answer (score 5):

A quick and dirty look at the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) would have revealed this

> Only subsequent events in a queue are delayed;  for example this will
>   not delay the no-arguments forms of .show() or .hide() which do not
>   use the effects queue.

Answer (score 2):

`hide()` just sets the `display` to `none` so no animation takes place which could be queued.

Try:

```
$('#second_div').show().delay(2000).queue(function (n) {
  $(this).hide();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RMMRj/1/

Also you should note jquerys disclaimer about `delay`:

> The .delay() method is best for delaying between queued jQuery
>   effects. Because it is limited—it doesn't, for example, offer a way to
>   cancel the delay—.delay() is not a replacement for JavaScript's native
>   setTimeout function, which may be more appropriate for certain use
>   cases.

So this is probably more appropriate:

```
setTimeout(function () {
  $('#second_div').hide();
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You did not specify a time for .hide()

for example .hide(2000);

you can delay it from there.

Comment: ? But delay will be executed before .hide() (which, wait 2 seconds). After hide should start, and hide my elements (but for 2 seconds I should still see it). The same logic is for delay()....

Comment: yeah but this would not work on .hide() or .show().

refer here

http://api.jquery.com/delay/

"for example this will not delay the no-arguments forms of .show() or .hide() which do not use the effects queue."